# Python argparse set 1 or more parameters to an argument

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameters, argparse

So basically I do sit on my code working with argparse framework but I do have one problem, which I don't know how to implement.

Basically I have multiple functions which I saved into an dict, so I can call it by the key and those have multiple parameter (and more to come)

So the input of all things is in the last line of the code which I commented out as should RUN like this:

The outcome should be the name of the Key() and the values which are parsed into the arguments (VALUE1, VALUE2........)

```
#filename: testfiler.py
import argparse

def filterOne(par1):
    print(par1)

def filterTwo(par1,par2):
    print(par1,par2)

def filterThree(par1,par2,par3):
    print(par1,par2,par3)

#.... more functions to come

filters = {
    "filterOneKey": filterOne,
    "filterTwoKey": filterTwo,
    "filterThreeKey": filterThree
}

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--filter', choices= (list(filters.keys()))) 
parser.add_argument('--filteragrument',metavar='Value',nargs='+') #not sure if it is correct

args = parser.parse_args()
filter = args.filter(args.filteragrument) #not sure if it is correct

print(filter) #show key() ✔️, but need to show the parameter which are parsed into filterargument (Value1,Value2....) 


#should RUN like this:
#python Tool/testfilter.py --filter filterTwoKey --filterargument Value1=23,Value2=55
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is get the function by the `filter` argument, and call it with `filter_arguments` (note that I fixed a typo, changed the argument name to follow the convention and removed `metavar` as you don't really need it)

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--filter', choices=list(filters.keys()))
parser.add_argument('--filter-arguments', nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args()
filters[args.filter](*args.filter_arguments)
```

Then you can execute

```
$ python test.py --filter filterOneKey --filter-arguments a
a

$ python test.py --filter filterTwoKey --filter-arguments a b
a b

$ python test.py --filter filterThreeKey --filter-arguments a b c
a b c
```

Of course you should use defensive programming to account for cases where the script is executed with a name of a function that is not in the dict (using `try-except` or `.get`) or a case where the number of provided arguments does not match the provided function name (with `try-except` or `*args`).

Comment: OMGGG!!!!! thank you very very much first with the really quick answer and 2nd with helping me out I was srsly struggling the whole day with that error.

I do have a questions
why -  filter-argument and filter_argument ? is it somewhere written in the doc?

Comment: I quite didnt understood what you mean with try-except or.get because I am really new into programming and that is a small project for me 

Comment: I'd avoid using flags that could be interpreted as abbreviations of each other.  Using something simple for '--filter-arguments'.